# Sorting sub array values in MultiDimension Array

Tags: php, sorting

I am trying to sort an array sent from an XML feed.

The Array looks like this from print_r($answer);:

```
Array
(
[size] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1.5m x 1.5m
        [1] => 1.5m x 3m
        [2] => 3m x 6.0m
        [3] => 3m x 2.3m
    )

[rate] => Array
    (
        [0] => 80
        [1] => 135
        [2] => 295
        [3] => 180
    )

[sortorder] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => 4
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 2
    )
.
.
.
)
```

I want to get out the array:

```
    Array
(
[size] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3m x 6.0
        [1] => 3m x 2.3m
        [2] => 1.5m x 1.5m
        [3] => 1.5m x 3m
    )

[rate] => Array
    (
        [0] => 295
        [1] => 180
        [2] => 80
        [3] => 135
    )

[sortorder] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
        [3] => 4
    )
.
.
.
)
```

What I am trying to do is use the Sort Order sub array to display the items in that order

I have tried a number of uasort() and array_multisort()  examples, but all seem to order the sub arrays and not the values inside the sub arrays

Any ideas will be a great help. Cheers

Comment: What I'd suggest is first sort your 'sortorder' array, then use the keys to repopulate your other arrays in individual loops. or re-organize your array structure so it makes more sense (size and rate and order are off the same branch for each item)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one sorts `$answer['sortorder']` and uses those keys to sort the rest of `$answer` without restructuring first.

```
// sort $answer['sortorder'] and retrieve indices.
asort($answer['sortorder']);
$idx = array_keys($answer['sortorder']); 

// do sorting
$sorted = array();
foreach($answer as $key=>$subarr) {
    if ($key != 'sortorder') { // don't sort
    foreach($idx as $i) {
        $sorted[$key][] = $subarr[$i];
    }
    } else {
        // $answer['sortorder'] is already sorted.
        $sorted[$key] = $subarr;
    }
}
print_r($sorted);
```

See it in action [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/QE7Y1x).

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Very graceful solution as it takes the array as it is. Thanks heaps :)

Answer (score 0):

This approach will re-structure the array with the sort order being the index, sort the array, then return it to it's original structure.

```
echo '<pre>';

$array['size'][0] = '1.5m x 1.5m';
$array['size'][1] = '1.5m x 3m';
$array['size'][2] = '3m x 6.0m';
$array['size'][3] = '3m x 2.3m';

$array['rate'][0] = 80;
$array['rate'][1] = 135;
$array['rate'][2] = 295;
$array['rate'][3] = 180;

$array['sortorder'][0] = 3;
$array['sortorder'][1] = 4;
$array['sortorder'][2] = 1;
$array['sortorder'][3] = 2;

$temp = array();
foreach($array['sortorder'] as $key => $value)
{
  $temp[$array['sortorder'][$key]] = array(
    'size'=>$array['size'][$key],
    'rate'=>$array['rate'][$key],
    'sortorder'=>$array['sortorder'][$key]
  );
}
ksort($temp);
$array = array();
foreach($temp as $key => $value)
{
  $array['size'][] = $value['size'];
  $array['rate'][] = $value['rate'];
  $array['sortorder'][] = $value['sortorder'];
}

print_r($array);
```

Comment: I would need to extract the array and format in this way before attempting the sort. I was hoping of reading directly from the array structure

Answer (score 0):

May I propose to use a different array structure that bundles each size, rate and sort order into one item:

```
array(
    array('size' => '...', 'rate' => '...', 'sort order' => '...'),
    ...
)
```

That makes it trivial to sort, and in fact easier to work with in general.
This PHP 5.3+ code does this transformation and sorting:

```
$answer = array_map(function ($size, $rate, $sortorder) {
              return compact('size', 'rate', 'sortorder');
          }, $answer);
usort($answer, function ($a, $b) { return $a['sortorder'] - $b['sortorder']; });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no control over the array structure. I was hoping to use usort as you have mentioned, but none of the examples I saw dealt with this kind of data

Comment: Well, you can "disassemble" the array again afterwards into its original format if you really need to...